# How to export an object returned by async/await method

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

As Async always returns promise, we have to resolve it to get the value. I need to export it's value (returned object) so that we can use it in another module.

```
export const getClient = async () => {

  return await HttpService.getValueFromSettings('durl').then((response) => {
    if(isValidResponse(response)) {
        endpoint = response.data;
        export const client = createClient(response.data);
        //This is where getting error that we can not export in side the function
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I need to use client in another module.

I tried to declare and initialize client object before calling, but didn't work:

```
export let client = null;
export const getClient = async () => {
 return await HttpService.getValueFromSettings('durl').then((response) => {
    if(isValidResponse(response)) {
        endpoint = response.data;
        client = createClient(response.data);
        return client;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a method and call it in every place you need it?

Comment: because I have to get the data via API and the places I need to use shows error as they can't wait till the method returns result.

Answer (score 9):

I'm fairly certain you can't do what you want, at least not directly.

Instead, you should just export the `getClient()` function itself and just call that when you need the client.

```
import { getClient } from './myfile';

getClient().then(client => { someOtherFunction(client); });
```

`import` and `export` are decided synchronous, so you won't be able to mix and match them with an asynchronous function.

The problem with your second example is you set `client = null`. When you then later set it to an object, you are setting that variable to an object, but you exported the **value** of `client` at export

Comment: I tried that, the issues is that the places I need to use getClient expects certain objects. Further, getClient returns Promise object and which throws compilation error I try to assign somewhere.

Comment: @TechTurtle in that case, your problem can't be solved, because you're trying to convert asynchronous code so it runs synchronously.

Comment: @TechTurtle In that case, you'll need to redesign things and possibly wrap those other things in promises as well. JavaScript doesn't have a mechanism to force async code to be synchronous (other then doing something really ugly like forcing a loop, but that'll freeze your whole window while you do it). `await` and `async` are really just syntactical sugar for Promise. They don't give any fundamentally new feature.

Comment: @samanime do you know if the `resolved` promise response can be set at the top of a file and then accessed in code below through a `class` and it's methods?

Comment: @Marklar You can set the value to any variable that is within it's scope, which would include a top-level file variable, so yes. You'd just have to make sure you knew if the promise had already resolved or not already before trying to use it (usually just checking if it's null/undefined would be sufficient).

Comment: @samanime thanks for taking the time to reply. So for example, within the `.then` we could use `ourTopLevelVar = someResult`. And then we have `class OurClass` with method `ourMethod` and in the method we would do `if (ourTopLevelVar) {} else {}`. If it is not resolved do we then still need to call the function again and wait for it to resolve again? So the code (to wait) would still need to be present in each method? I don't expect you to google for me but I'm struggling to find examples of this, are you aware of any articles that cover this?

Comment: @Marklar Yes, you'd need to recall `ourMethod()` each time if it wasn't resolved, until it was. You can either do this with a `setTimeout()` in your else that tries again in x-number of seconds, or you could have your `.then()` call it directly, depending on your setup.

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible in modern browsers with [Top level await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await). Be sure to check browser support at the table below the example.

A simple example using fetch from MDN:

```
const colors = fetch('../data/colors.json')
  .then(response => response.json());

export default await colors;
```

The original script can be written like below and work as OP intended:

```
const client = HttpService.getValueFromSettings('durl').then((response) => {
  if(isValidResponse(response)) {
    return createClient(response.data);
  }
  return null;
};

export default await client;
```

Comment: although vs code warns me that await has no effect on export, it does...thanks!!