# How to export a variable inside self-invoking async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, async-await

I have a self-invoking `async function` which after running the file should export a `variable`, containing an `array` of `strings` with a bunch of `URLs`, then it will be imported into another file which I'll run afterward.

This is my code:

```
// file1.js
(async () => {
  // bunch of irrelevant code here

  // gets all URLs, formatted & store in this variable
  const availableFormattedUrls = formatUrls(allUrls); // I get all URLs here - array of strings

  module.exports = { availableFormattedUrls }; 
})();
```

Then I'm trying to export the `variable` to another file & print it like so:

```
// file2.js
const { availableFormattedUrls } = require('./file1.js');
console.log(availableFormattedUrls); // I get undefined here
```

I'm running these files through the terminal like so: `node file1.js && file2.js`, but I keep getting `undefined` in the second file.

I also tried it like so:

```
// file1.js
module.export = (async () => {
  ....
  ....

  return availableFormattedUrl; 
})();
```

But again, it doesn't work. What's happening?

Comment: Consider [Asynchronous nodejs module exports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20238829/asynchronous-nodejs-module-exports) and also [How to export an object returned by async/await method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43687092/how-to-export-an-object-returned-by-async-await-method). Basically you can't add an additional export after the fact. Your second attempt is more reasonable as now you are exporting a promise that should resolve to the desired url value. When you tried it that way, what about it "didn't work"?

Comment: @CRice thanks for your reply. The second attempt got me `undefined` as well. I'm not sure why?

Comment: After thinking about that a sec... You are exporting the return of an async function which means that the value of the export *has* to be a Promise of some sort. It shouldn't even be possible for that export to be `undefined`. Can you show how you are using the export? Perhaps the problem is on the consumer's side.

Comment: If you're exporting a promise, you'll have to use `await require('./file1.js')` or `require('./file1.js').then(…)`.

Comment: "*I'm running these files through the terminal like so: `node file1.js && file2.js`*" - uh, don't. That's running two separate scripts using bash syntax, the second one being an executable probably with a shebang? Instead, write a single program (consisting of multiple modules being required) and run only that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to export it like so:

```
module.export = (async () => {
  ....
  ....

  return availableFormattedUrl; 
})();
```

Then, imported it like so:

```
const availableFormattedUrls = require('./file1.js');
```

Finally, I was able to run it with the command `node file2.js`

Comment: Is there anything missing from here? I tried doing exactly this and it's still showing up as undefined

Answer (score 0):

I see one error:

in file2.js you are requiring the wrong file require('./fetch-urls');

instead of:

```
const { availableFormattedUrls } = require('./file1.js');
```

And you need to ensure that:

formatUrls(allUrls) is not returning undefined

Comment: That's a mistake that I made I have edited my code